# AngularJS highlight username with consecutive word

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a my angular binding as follows:

```
<p ng-bind="user.content"></p>
```

and it outputs as a string like the following text

```
@lorem ipsum dolor set amet
```

I would like it to print in html which adds span to the username @lorem with the next consecutive word ipsum. So the resulting html should become:

```
<span>@lorem ipsum</span> dolor set amet
```

I searched the web but found only a few solutions which were able to hightlight the username only with plain javascript and not with the next consecutive word. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't really know AngularJS, but if you could tell me one thing, I may be able to answer your question. Will the username always be the first word of the value of the `p` tag?

Comment: @JacquesMarais yes it will always be the first word. and i can use jQuery too to add the span

Comment: @charlietfl could you provide me the references or jsfiddle that might help with the answer

Comment: @SahilJariwala Updated my answer, it should work now.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately regex is only applicable to selector. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)
So you have to separate the user name from the rest of the text.

Usually, the text is already save with a `span` or a `pre` tag with the user name.

e.g:

`"Text text from <pre>@username</pre>."`

You can also create a directive: where you can search for the pattern:

`/^@[a-z0-9_-]{3,16}$/`

```js
angular.module('app').directive('addSpan', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.html
           return element.innerHTML.replace(/^@[a-z0-9_-]{3,16}$/,"<span class='username'>$0</span>");
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: can you help me with a jsfiddle as the above code seems not to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$('p').html(
    $('p')
        .html()
        .replace(/^([^\s]+)\s([^\s]+)/, "<span>$1 $2</span>")
);
```

Comment: You need to create the groups with ()  it will not work like this.